# State Updates But Does Not Trigger a Render When I Reassign an Object to an Existing Object

Tags: reactjs

[Source Code](https://github.com/stevepolitodesign/rails-react-example)

### This Works

```
const { id, title, complete, updated_at } = todoItem
...
todoItems[todoItemIndex].title = title
todoItems[todoItemIndex].complete = complete
todoItems[todoItemIndex].updated_at = updated_at
this.setState({ todoItems })
```

### This Doesn't Work

```
todoItems[todoItemIndex] = todoItem
this.setState({ todoItems })
```

or

```
todoItems[todoItemIndex] = { ...todoItem }
this.setState({ todoItems })
```

or

```
this.setState(state => {
    todoItems: state.todoItems.map(item => {
        if (item.id === todoItem.id) {
            item = { ...todoItem }
        }
        return item
    })
})
```

### Other Notes

I call `componentDidUpdate()` to confirm that `this.state.todoItems` is actually being updated when I use `todoItems[todoItemIndex] = { ...todoItem }`.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(this.state.todoItems)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [ryanhinerman](https://www.reddit.com/user/ryanhinerman/)
for [their answer on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/emiufy/state_updates_but_does_not_trigger_a_render_when/fdpi3y3/) as outlined below.

> The better solution is to not save the data from props inside the constructor. Instead, use `this.props.todoItem` directly. If you want to make it look prettier, you can destructure it at the top of the TodoItem's render function like so: const `{ todoItem } = this.props;`

---

What's actually happening here is going to be slightly difficult to explain, but it's important to your understanding of React, so hopefully I can do an okay job of explaining it.

```
constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    this.todoItem = this.props.todoItem;
}
```

This constructor is only going to be called one time for the lifetime of a component, at the initial creation. What you're doing here is taking `this.props.todoItem` at the initial creation and saving it inside the component. This constructor will not be called again, so `this.todoItems` will never be updated no matter how many times `this.props.todoItems changes`.

`<TodoItem todoItem={todoItem} key={todoItem.id} />`
Here we give our component a key, and when this key changes, React knows to recreate our component. Because the `id` of `todoItem` never changes, React never recreates that component. If we were to use todoItem.title or something, the key would change and the entire component would be reset and the constructor would be called again, "solving" the problem. This, however, isn't the correct solution.

The better solution is to not save the data from props inside the constructor. Instead, use `this.props.todoItem` directly. If you want to make it look prettier, you can destructure it at the top of the TodoItem's render function like so: const `{ todoItem } = this.props;`

Answer (score 0):

always update your state in immutable way, so the current solution and the other to options are not valid.
the problem with your last solution is that you forgot to put the a return or even better put a Parenthesis around the object that is being return by the updater func.

in your case

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    todoItems: prevState.todoItems.map(item => {
        if (item.id === todoItem.id) {
            return {...todoItem};
        }
        return item;
    }))
})
```